# How to add multiple events at a one time in outlook calendar using Microsoft Graph Rest API?

Tags: php, codeigniter, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, rest

Anyone, please tell me how to use batch API to create multiple events.
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/drive/root:/{file}:/content"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/planner/tasks"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{id}/events"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "url": "/me",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "body": {
        "city" : "Redmond"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MS Graph batch request payload that will create two events in the current user's calendar.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/calendar/events",
      "body": {
        "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
        "body": {
          "contentType": "HTML",
          "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
        },
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2021-09-04T12:00:00",
          "timeZone": "Africa/Nairobi"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2021-09-04T13:00:00",
          "timeZone": "Africa/Nairobi"
        },
        "location": {
          "displayName": "Harry's Bar"
        },
        "attendees": [
          {
            "emailAddress": {
              "address": "chris@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
              "name": "Chris Green"
            },
            "type": "required"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/calendar/events",
      "body": {
        "subject": "Let's go for Dinner",
        "body": {
          "contentType": "HTML",
          "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
        },
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2021-09-04T19:00:00",
          "timeZone": "Africa/Nairobi"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2021-09-04T20:00:00",
          "timeZone": "Africa/Nairobi"
        },
        "location": {
          "displayName": "Harry's Joint"
        },
        "attendees": [
          {
            "emailAddress": {
              "address": "peters@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
              "name": "Carl Peters"
            },
            "type": "required"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```